# CGI program timeout when reading/writing, respectively, from/to stdin/stdout

Tags: c, cgi

I have tested this program from the shell, and it works correctly when redircting stdin from a file.  However, when operating as a CGI program, it times out (TimeForCGI hiawatha webserver setting is set to 30 seconds).  This program is contained in just one file.  It should be noted that this program was written only to physically verify what I have been reading about C.G.I., and I chose C (or anything else that generates a binary executable) so I can be sure that these things have been untouched by any interpreter, as might be done to facilitate their abstractions.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <error.h>

int main (void);

int
main
(void)
{
  static char buf[BUFSIZ];
  size_t size;

  if (setvbuf (stdout, NULL, _IOFBF, BUFSIZ) != 0)
    error (EXIT_FAILURE, errno, "setvbuf(), stdout");
  if (setvbuf (stdin, NULL, _IOFBF, BUFSIZ) != 0)
    error (EXIT_FAILURE, errno, "setvbuf(), stdin");
  if (setvbuf (stderr, NULL, _IOLBF, BUFSIZ) != 0)
    error (EXIT_FAILURE, errno, "setvbuf(), stderr");
  printf ("Content-Type: text/plain\n\n");
  if (fflush (stdout) == EOF)
    error (EXIT_FAILURE, errno, "fflush()");
  for (;;)
    {
      size = fread (buf,1, BUFSIZ, stdin);
      if (size == 0)
        {
          if (feof (stdin) != 0)
            goto quit;
          else
            error (EXIT_FAILURE, errno, "fread(), stdin");
        }
      size = fwrite (buf, 1, size, stdout);
      if (size == 0)
        error (EXIT_FAILURE, errno, "write(), stdout");
    }
 quit:
  fflush (stdout);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is the corresponding html form;

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="form-process.cgi" method="post">
      input_a: <input name="input_a" type="text"><br>
      input_b: <input name="input_b" type="text"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't check for errors from `fread` or `fwrite`.  Your environment is different and, as stated in @johnbollinger's answer, the server is not forced to signal eof condition (to close your process' input)  You need to check for `Content-length`.

Comment: Why do you disable buffers and then use `fread`/`fwrite` calls instead of `read`/`write`system calls?  Do you want buffering after all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program attempts to read from its standard input until it reaches its end.  That's fine when you redirect the input from a file, but it is inappropriate for a CGI program.  The web server in which the CGI runs is not obligated to signal end-of-file on the input when the end of the request body is reached.  If it does not, then your program will block indefinitely in `fread()`.

There are several reasons why EOF might not be signaled at the end of the request body.  The RFC explicitly postulates the presence of extension data, but it is also plausible that the server connects the CGI's standard input directly to the network socket on which the request is coming in.  EOF will not normally be detected there until and unless the client closes its end of the connection, which many clients *do not* do between requests, and which many of the rest do not do until after they have received the response.

Accordingly, the CGI specifications in [RFC 3875](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875) say "the script MUST NOT attempt to read more than CONTENT_LENGTH bytes, even if more data is available" (section 4.2).  The CONTENT_LENGTH is conveyed to the script via an environment variable of that name, provided that the request specifies one.  Your CGI must not read more bytes than the variable specifies, and it must not read *any* bytes if the content length is not specified at all.  On the other hand, it is at the CGI's not required to read the whole request body, or any of it at all.

Comment: thank you for your excellent explanation.  I have, in the meantime, tried an algorithm that uses getchar and putchar the number of times specified by the value of  atoi(getenv ("CONTENT_LENGTH")).  For the sake of future readers of this thread, the correct program is provided in a subsequent post.

Comment: Your answer also explains why using the unix utility cat copied to cat.cgi in my webroot didn't work either.

Comment: @RobinMiyagi, if you use `getchar`/`putchar`, don't deactivate buffering.  Just make use of the `fflush` function and flush the buffers when you have to, but don't deactivate them, or you'll get a serious penalty in performance.

Comment: I did not deactivate buffering, I enabled full buffering.  As I had posted earlier, exit flushes and closes all stdio buffers, and exit is called by the compiler hosted startup code after return from main.  Also, full buffering greatly increases the performance.

Comment: And what hapens when CONTENT_LENGTH itself is malformed? How do you sanitize CONTENT_LENGTH?

Comment: @AhmadBilal, this question and answer are about normal operation of CGI.  If the incoming request is malformed or prematurely truncated then that's primarily an issue for the host server to handle, not the concern of CGI programs.

Comment: how will the server handle it? Isn't the CGI program at risk as well.. since we need to read the CONTENT_LENGTH value in the program above specifically to sanitize the message body(stdin)?

Comment: it appears that he is using a preset static buffer, instead of reading CONTENT_LENGTH and using that as buffer to limit stdin size. Is this okay?

Comment: @AhmadBilal, your analysis regarding the buffer is incorrect.  Although each `fread()` call provides a fixed-size buffer, he loops to perform as many `fread()` calls as are needed to obtain the whole input.  *Each one* reads up to `BUFSIZ` bytes, regardless of how many the previous one read.

Comment: @AhmadBilal, as for how the server might handle it, that is far too broad even for a whole SO question in its own right.

Comment: @John Bollinger, I can physically verify that Hiawatha does the following.
The server MUST set this meta-variable if and only if the request is accompanied by a message-body entity.
The CONTENT_LENGTH value must reflect the length of the message-body after the server has removed any
transfer-codings or content-codings.

In fact hiawatha may be configured to ban visitors who send malformed request messages.  Thank you for bringing my attention to RFC3875.  This document provided all the information I needed to make my [application cloud](https://www.linuxprogramming.ca/) operational.

Comment: In my production code, all data provided by the visitor has been sanitized using iscntrl(3), after decoding the %xx encodings.

Comment: I have also physically verified that hiawatha does not accept control characters in request messages, even when %xx encoded.  Of course, with other web servers, this may not be the case.  The production code sanitizes the input anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I have done this;

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <error.h>
#include <dstralg.h>

int main (void);

int
main
(void)
{
  int l;
  int i;

  if (setvbuf (stdin, NULL, _IOFBF, BUFSIZ)!= 0)
    error (EXIT_FAILURE, errno, "sevbuf(), stdin");
  if (setvbuf (stdout, NULL, _IOFBF, BUFSIZ)!= 0)
    error (EXIT_FAILURE, errno, "sevbuf(), stdout");
  printf ("Content-Type: text/plain\n\n");
  l = atoi (getenv ("CONTENT_LENGTH"));
  for (i = 0; i < l; ++i)
    putchar (getchar ());
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

which exhibits the desired behavior.  The full buffering greatly reduces the overhead of processing one character at a time, and is only a function call once getchar and putchar have been unwound (assuming libc has been dynamically linked).  As this is only experimental code using data from Hiawatha, which I trust, I didn't bother checking the return values of getchar and putchar being  error conditions.  Nor did I bother to check if CONTENT_LENGTH was NULL or "".  In practice, I would use a domain specific interpretted language, such as PHP, for small projects with light traffic.  I would probably use C/C++ for demanding workloads, although FastCGI can improve performance by the lighter operation of opening and closing connection to a unix domain socket in place of the heavier operation of forking a child process with the expense of creating page tables and all the other process management book keeping.

Comment: What do you mean with the fulll buffering.  You have deactivated the stdio package full buffering to use yours, so you cannot use `fflush(3)` call and so get benefit from using the `getchar(3)`/`putchar(3)` calls.  Your _full buffering_ is far from complete (at least for the complete stdio buffering :) )

Comment: According to `man 3 exit': All open stdio(3) streams are flushed and closed. Files created by tmpfile(3) are removed, at least for the GNU C library. As C.G.I. programs tend to be in house software, portability was not a priority of this project.

Answer (score 0):

The following code, from your last post, should do also:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <error.h>
#include <dstralg.h>

int main (void);

int
main
(void)
{
    int l;
    int i;

    printf ("Content-Type: text/plain\n\n");
    l = atoi (getenv ("CONTENT_LENGTH"));
    for (i = 0; i < l; ++i)
        putchar (getchar ());
    fflush(stdout);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and without the final `fflush(stdout);` also, because you are going to `exit(2)` inmediately, after last `putchar(3);`, and that will make *stdio* to flush all buffers remaining.

Comment: According to `man 3 exit': All open stdio(3) streams are flushed and closed.  Files created by tmpfile(3) are removed, at least for the GNU C library.  As C.G.I. programs tend to be in house software, portability was not a priority of this project.

Comment: @RobinMiyagi, as you read in my post, _...and without the final `fflush(stdout);` also *because your are goint go `exit(2)` inmediately*..._ But if you are not going to `exit()` then it is better to use `fflush()` with stdio, so you can warrant you are not waiting for something while your last output stays on the output buffer, CGI output is not warranted to be to a tty, so you are not warranted a flush after a `\n`, as in interactive programs.

Comment: _exit(2) is the underlying system call.  However, at least with G.N.U., it is the the library wrapper function to this system call, exit(3) that is actually called, and does library function cleanup.  The buffering is actually a higher level construct provided by the library, and when you are using the read/write system calls directly, you must, if you wish to have buffering, provide this functionality yourself.  According to the system documentation, exit performs all functions with atexit(3), flushes all stdio buffers and then closes all open files.

Comment: @what happens if someone passes you a malformed "CONTENT_LENGTH" and knowing atoi can't properly handle non-null terminated strings?

Comment: @RobinMiyagi, yes, I've made a typo.... sorry :) but I think that's not the actual problem, right?

Comment: @AhmadBilal, the CGI standard says the `CONTENT_LENGTH` environment variable is the place to find how much you have to read.  If you install a cgi on a such working container (a lying one), reading until `EOF` is detected will not solve the problem, but you'll get it worse, I'm afraid.

Comment: @AhmadBilal, According to RFC3875, section 4.1.2 (CONTENT_LENGTH), The server MUST set this meta-variable if and only if the request is accompanied by a message-body entity.
The CONTENT_LENGTH value must reflect the length of the message-body after the server has removed any
transfer-codings or content-codings, as had been pointed out by John Bollinger. I can physically confirm that this is exactly what hiawatha does, and, also according to RFC3875, _must_ do.  In fact, Hiawatha bans visitors that send malformed request messages.

Comment: I have read that section, and the the 'server' referred to here is the sending server. It is supposed to do so and so. Just like, a person is not supposed to murder anyone. In a malformed request, a person would send a non-null-terminated or/and excessively long string to cause bufferoverflow.

Comment: requests can be malformed in multiple ways, it is not necessary that hiawatha takes care of them all. Unless you are saying, that you have seen the code that deals with CONTENT_LENGTH abnormality?